# Seating $2n$ people around a table with each person has at most $n-1$ friends

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to show that with the setting in the title, that it is always possible to arrange the seats so that no person sits beside his/her friend.

I am not good at this kinds of problems at all, the only method I could think of is to use induction, but with the induction hypothesis (statement holds for $2(n-1)$ people) the situation seems complicated when I have $2n$ people to arrange as I could not easily single out $2$ person, any suggestions?

Comment: You are looking for a Hamilton circuit of the complement of the friendship graph.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for your suggestion, I am kind new to combinatorics, I am reading about Hamilton circuit now on wikipedia, but I do not seems to get the intuition behind, can you explain this a little bit in a less technical way? Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably not much help if you haven't studied Hamilton cycles yet. The graph in mind is the graph with people as nodes and an edge between two people of they are *not* friends.  So a hamilton circuit in this graph would be exactly what you want to show exists.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see, I didn't study Hamilton cycles, would it be possible to do something without these knowledge?

Comment: To me this smells of an application of the pigeonhole principle. Haven't looked closer, though.

Comment: If you haven't studied Hamiltonian cycles yet, then now is the time to start to study them. Look for a theorem that says that if each of $2n$ vertices has degree at least $n$, then there's a Hamiltonian cycle. Or, look for a theorem that says that if each pair of vertices has degree adding up to at least the number of vertices of the graph, then the graph has a Hamiltonian cycle. Look in some graph theory textbooks.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,shouldn't  we be looking for a theorem that says that if a graph containing $2n$ vertices has degree at least ** $n+1$ ** ,then there's a Hamiltonian cycle?

Comment: @rah, I don't think so --- no vertex is adjacent to itself.

Comment: @Gerry,I don't understand.Let us at first draw the friendship graph.The vertices have degree at most n-1 but there are 2n vertices.So when we draw the complement graph,shouldn't each vertex have degree at least n+1?Therefore aren't we looking for a Hamiltonian cycle in a graph where each vertex has degree at least n+1?

Comment: @rah, no vertex is adjacent to itself. No vertex is adjacent to itself. No vertex is adjacent to itself. The maximum possible degree of a vertex is $2n-1$, not $2n$. No vertex is adjacent to itself. The degree in a graph, plus the degree in the complement, adds up to $2n-1$, not $2n$. No vertex is adjacent to itself.

Comment: @Gerry,ah,right.Please ignore my previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be answered using [Ore's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem), which states that if $G$ is a (finite, simple) graph with $n\ge3$ vertices, and if $$\deg v+\deg w\ge n$$ for every pair of non-adjacent vertices $v$ and $w$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian, that is, there is a cycle in the graph that contains every vertex in the graph. The Wikipedia essay contains a short proof of Ore's Theorem.

The Wikipedia essay also notes that Ore's Theorem is a strengthening of Dirac's Theorem, which states that if each vertex of an $n$-vertex graph $G$ has degree at least $n/2$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian. Dirac's Theorem will suffice for solving the question here.